# How to refresh changed buttons in jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery UI dialog which is initialized

```
$('#jqDialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  buttons: { 'Ok': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } },
});
```

and then I want to change the buttons programatically w/o re-initializing the plugin instance.

```
$('#jqDialog')
  .dialog('options',
  { 
    buttons: {
      'Ok': function () {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        store(id);
      },
      'Cancel': function () { $(this).dialog('close'); }
    }
  })
  .dialog('open');
```

When the dialog window is opened it still have the original button. With the Button plugin you have to call .button("refresh"). Is there a similar method that needs to be called with the Dialog plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have just needs a tweak, the method name is [`'option'`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-option) (no `s`) like this:

```
.dialog('option',
```

This works even when the dialog's open, [you can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hSL2N/).

Comment: @ChrisP - I've done this particular one at least a dozen times...definitely not intuitively named :)

Answer (score 0):

The only wrong thing in your code is the use of the word `options` instead of `option` as in the following code

```
$("jqDialog").dialog("option", "buttons", 
    { 
        "Ok": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could destroy the dialog first by calling $dlg.dialog('destory'). and reevaluate the dialog you want.

Comment: This approach would remove all the other options already set w/ the dialog. My goal is to re-use the dialog across different situations.